# Multi Column DDPLY/R function in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, plyr

I have the following statement in R

```
library(plyr)
filteredData <- ddply(data, .(ID1, ID2), businessrule)
```

I am trying to use Python and Pandas to duplicate the action. 
I have tried...

```
data['judge'] = data.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).apply(lambda x: businessrule(x))
```

But this provides error...

```
 incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message can be reproduced with

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=['ID1', 'ID2', 'val'])
df['new'] = df.groupby(['ID1', 'ID2']).apply(lambda x: x.values.sum())
# TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

It is likely that your code raises an error for the same reason this toy example does.
The right-hand side is a Series with a 2-level MultiIndex:

```
ID1  ID2
0    1       3
3    4      12
6    7      21
9    10     30
dtype: int64
```

`df['new'] = ...` tells Pandas to assign this Series to a column in `df`.
But `df` has a single-level index:

```
   ID1  ID2  val
0    0    1    2
1    3    4    5
2    6    7    8
3    9   10   11
```

Because the single-level index is incompatible with the 2-level MultiIndex, the
assignment fails. It is in general never correct to assign the result of
`groupby/apply` to a columns of `df` unless the columns or levels you group by
also happen to be valid index keys in the original DataFrame, `df`.

Instead, assign the Series to a new variable, *just like what the R code does*:

```
filteredData = data.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).apply(businessrule)
```

Note that `lambda x: businessrule(x)` can be replaced with `businessrule`.